# Passing a get method in a set method

Tags: c++, setter, getter

I'm new to OOP and trying to self-learn.

I'm not sure about the logical implementation of this simple (I feel that it's very simple, but I have a mental block) exercise:

- Create an `Employee` class, with `name`, `surname` and `salary` fields
- Create 2 employees and print their salary after and before a 10% increase.

So, here are my files:

```
// employee.h

#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <string>
    using std::string;


class Employee {


private:
    string name;
    string surname;
    float salary;

public:
    Employee(string,string,float);
    void setName(string);
    void setSurname(string);
    void setSalary(float);
    string getName();
    string getSurname();
    float getSalary();

};


#endif // EMPLOYEE
```

---

```
employee.cpp
#include "employee.h"

Employee::Employee(string n,string c,float stip) {

Employee::setName(n);
Employee::setSurname(c);
Employee::setSalary(stip);

}


void Employee::setName(string n){

name=n;

}
void Employee::setSurname(string c){

surname=c;

}

void Employee::setSalary(float stip){

salary=(stip>=0)?stip:0;

}


string Employee::getName(){


return name;

}

string Employee::getSurname(){


return surname;

}

float Employee::getSalary(){

return salary;

}
```

---

```
increase.h
#ifndef INCREASE_H
#define INCREASE_H

namespace Increase {

    const float inc2017=1.1;

}



#endif // INCREASE_H
```

About that Main file I've considered 2 possibilities:

1) Using a variable to locally save the salary

```
float prov=a.getSalary();

a.setSalary(prov*Increase::inc017);
```

2) Passing the get method in the set method :

```
a.setSalary(a.getSalary()*Increase::inc2017);
```

Which is better?

Is number 2 logically correct or do I bypass encapsulation in this way?

(I know that it wasn't really necessary using a namespace header in this small problem, but I'm working toward a larger project and I would like to be mentally prepared for it)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with getters and setters or encapsulation, and almost all of the code you have posted is irrelevant. You're just asking whether to pre-fetch the result of a function call into a variable before using it, right? And that's a subjective question anyway.

Comment: Why don't you make an `increaseSalaryBy` function? =)

Comment: ^ I second @SingerOfTheFall wholeheartedly. Encapsulation is about program logic, not making direct variable access as verbose as possible.

Comment: @George, if your `getSalary()` return a reference to the enclosed member variable, you are really bypassing encapsulation: just make `salary` public if you want to go that way, which I would not.

Comment: @George, `just don't make too many bespoke functions for manipulating one value`, well, this is just the matter of business logic of the application, and the amount of reused code. If business logic dictates that a certain operation is frequently used (especially if it's used from multiple places in the application), it definitely should be extracted into a separate method/class/whatever. Anyway, I feel this is a little out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the specific question you had: It's perfectly fine to not use a temporary variable when setting a new value.

Once the value is extracted out, it can't possibly break encapsulation, because we're talking about code that doesn't touch the insides of the object at all.

A solution suggested in comments, which could make the class a bit more closed/specific, would be a dedicated "increase by" member function, but it's up to you to decide whether this class should have this functionality insider, or whether you e.g. want to delegate the increase to another component.

As a rule of thumb, if the class doesn't have additional logic around the invariants of its members', the members can be made public - that way you get rid of getters and setters and your question answers itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your getter function is:

```
float Employee::getSalary(){

    return salary;

}
```

Note that this function is returning a copy of the member salary. The user of this function is no way able to change the value of member variable `salary`.

Had your getter function returned a reference to `salary`, the user may have been able to change the value of `salary` member variable, thereby breaking encapsulation.

```
float& Employee::getSalary(){

    return salary;

}
```

So, you should not be concerned about breaking encapsulation with the getter function you have written.

Comment: Returning a reference to `salary` **is** breaking encapsulation. Why not declare `salary` public? would it be any different, from encapsulation point?

Comment: Returning a reference to a private member via a getter function  is as good a declaring the member public.

Comment: @Rishi I'd disagree. You have to add another method for absolutely no reason.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, sorry I didn't follow. The second method I have put is to exemplify a wrong practice and it should be avoided. The reason I added it is because OP wanted to know if encapsulation is getting broken using a getter method.